# Биндинг в WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, mvvm-light

Пытаюсь разобраться с MVVM. Имеется проект MVVM Light. В нем в представлении есть DataGrid, который я хочу привязать к ObservableCollection (нужен только один столбец).

DataGrig сопоставляю с ObservableCollection:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridRowName" ItemsSource="{Binding RowName}"...
```

В модели представления пишу:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;

    private ObservableCollection<string> _rowName = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> RowName
    {
        get { return _rowName; }
        set { Set(ref _rowName, value); }
    }

    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;

        _dataService.GetData(
            (item, error) =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    RowName.Add("T" + (i + 1));
            });
    }
```

Вместо строк "Т1", "Т2" и "Т3" вижу "2", "2", "2". Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А что в вашей коллекции `_rowName`?

Comment: А почему не реализован интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: ViewModelBase, от которого наследуется MainViewModel, наследуется от ObservableObject, который реализует INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: _rowName это массив, содержащий названия строк. Он заполняется элементами "T1", "T2", "T3", и это действительно так (проверено отладчиком), но выводится таблицу "2", "2", "2".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Одна из найболее часто встречающихся ошибок у новичков - запомните, привязка данных работает со свойствами. Подозреваю, что колонки у вас генерируются автоматически, поэтому столбцами будут выступать открытые свойства типа привязанной коллекции.

Для вашего примера - у типа `string` есть только одно открытое свойство - `Length`, поэтому вы получаете такие странные (на первый взгляд) результаты.

```
"T1".Length // => 2
"T2".Length // => 2
"T3".Length // => 2
```

Один из способ получить правильный результат, установить столбцы для `DataGrid` в разметке:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RowName}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="Header" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Не забывайте установить

```
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

иначе получите лишние столбцы

Comment: Спасибо! Это решило проблему!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте посмотреть [Пример](https://github.com/Teren2304/BlockApp). Там привязка и работа с ObservableCollection. Я бы советовал Вам для начала заполнять данные коллекции отдельно в модели, чтоб она была не зависима, а потом просто получать во ViewModel.